# Can female Autobots take up the position of leadership?

Tags: transformers

In Transformers: the movie we know of course that the Matrix of leadership was given to Ultra Magnus, later Hot Rod receives it and destroys Unicron. But why couldn't someone like Arcee become leader and get the Matrix. Are females allowed to be leader or even have the Matrix and be the guardian of it?

Comment: Possibly of interest; http://tfwiki.net/wiki/Female_Transformer - "*Well, I remember bringing up that question early on with Hasbro, "are any of these female?" And then I think Hasbro's attitude was, 'this is a boy toy. We don't wanna have, you know, girl robots.' So, I said, "OK, just want to clarify that.*"

Comment: *"GN: Were Soundwave and Arcee the two characters you most would have liked to see in the film? ... 
Orci: Those two were kind of the main ones ... I would have liked to see Arcee, but the idea of a female Transformer needs its own explanation, and there just wasn't going to be enough time. It would have been like, "Oh, that's convenient. They're trying to appease women with a pink Transformer." So rather than having that happen, let it just be a straight shot and speak for itself right now."* http://uk.ign.com/articles/2007/07/02/exclusive-interview-robert-orci?page=3

Comment: related, not dupe: [Why does only Hot Rod get magically reformatted by the Matrix of Leadership?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/63059/5184). There's some good discussion about who can hold/carry/wield the matrix.

Comment: @Richard It's bizarre that they assumed the color palette would stay the same when they mangled every other 'bot and 'con except Prime.

Answer (score 4):

> The concept of the Matrix originates from the brain of Marvel Comics
>   writer Bob Budiansky and is a result of the "no girls"/"no gender"
>   policy enforced by Hasbro regarding their then-new robot brand.
>   Because there were no female robots/the robots had no gender,
>   Budiansky came up with an asexual method of reproduction in the form
>   of the Creation Matrix, a "Primal Program" housed within the Autobot
>   leader that could bring new Transformers to life, which would also
>   prove a helpful plot device when he was required to introduce new
>   characters to the series

[Transformers Wiki](http://tfwiki.net/wiki/Matrix_of_Leadership)

As the concept of the Matrix predates female Autobots, it was never shown in the hands of a female Autobot in the comics. In the cartoons since, **there has never been a female holder of the Matrix of Leadership -- but there is no indication that this is due to any sort of a rule**; the Matrix has been passed to the next most qualified (present) individual in each case that it has come up -- and in almost every situation, there were no female Autobots there to be considered!

Perhaps the best support for female Autobots being able to assume the <s>Mantle</s> Matrix of Leadership is the fact that there have, through history, been several female Autobot resistance leaders.  Elita One and Beta were the highest ranking Autobots on Cybertron in their time (Elita because Prime was gone, Beta because she was one of the first Transformers to rebel against the Quintessons). **The Autobots are clearly an egalitarian society suffering from a severe shortage of females** -- but as they don't sexually reproduce, they probably never saw a need to have more made.

Final thoughts: in Prime's final words in the movie, the Matrix is destined to fall in the hands of an Autobot who would use its powers to light their darkest hour. He didn't designate a gender.

Comment: That does make sense, but in the movie Arcee is there. Which is why it is a little confusing.

Comment: @Elizabeth She's literally the lowest ranked person there, though.